# Using python 3 for recursive Boolean check if a list is sorted

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x, sortedlist

I am trying to write a recursive function that does a Boolean check if a list is sorted. return true if list is sorted and false if not sorted. So far I am trying to understand if I have the 'base case' correct (ie, my first 'if' statement):

```
def isSorted(L, i=[]):
    if L[i] > L[i + 1]:
         return false
    else:
         return true
```

Am I correct with my initial `if "L[i] > L[i + 1]:"` as base case for recursion?

Assuming my 'base case' is correct I am not sure how to recursively determine if the list is sorted in non-descending order.

Answer (score 1):

here is what I came up with. I designate the default list to `0`; first check to see if first item is the last item. if not, should check each item until it reaches the end of the list.

```
def isSorted(L):
    # Base case
    if len(L) == 1:
        return True

return L[0] <= L[1] and isSorted(L[1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would start.  Write a function with the following signature:

```
function isSorted(currentIndex, collection)
```

Inside the function, check to see if `currentIndex` is at the end of the collection.  If it is, return true.

Next, check to see if `collection[index]` and `collection[index+1]` are sorted correctly.

If they aren't, return false
If they are, return `isSorted(currentIndex+1, collection)`

**Warning**:  this is a horrible use for recursion

Comment: thanks for the insight. I will try to process the logic and see what i can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

No, the base case will be when you reach the end of the list, in which case you return true.

Otherwise, if the two elements you are looking at are out of order return false.

Otherwise, return the result of a recursive call on the next elements down the list.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MStodd: recursion is not the way to solve this problem in Python.  For a very long list, Python may overflow its stack!  But for short lists it should be okay, and if your teacher gave you this problem, you need to do it this way.

Here is how you should think about this problem.  Each recursive call you should do one of three things: 0) return `False` because you have found that the list is not sorted; 1) return `True` because you have reached your base case; 2) break the work down and make the remaining problem smaller somehow, until you reach your base case.  The base case is the case where the work cannot be broken down any further.

Here is a broad outline:

```
def recursive_check(lst, i):
    # check at the current position "i" in list
    # if check at current position fails, return False
    # update current position i
    # if i is at the end of the string, and we cannot move it any more, we are done checking; return true
    # else, if i is not at the end of the string yet, return the value returned by a recursive call to this function
```

For example, here is a function that checks to see if there is a character `'@'` in the string.  It should return `True` if there is no `@` anywhere in the string.

```
def at_check(s, i):
    if s[i] == '@':
        return False
    i += 1
    if i >= len(s):
        return True
    else:
        return at_check(s, i)
```

I wrote the above exactly like the outline I gave above.  Here is a slightly shorter version that does the same things, but not in exactly the same order.

```
def at_check(s, i=0):
    if i >= len(s):
        return True
    if s[i] == '@':
        return False
    return at_check(s, i+1)
```

EDIT: notice that I put `i=0` in the arguments to `at_check()`.  This means that the "default" value of `i` will be 0.  The person calling this function can just call `at_check(some_string)` and not explicitly pass in a 0 for the first call; the default argument will provide that first 0 argument.

The only time we really need to add one to `i` is when we are recursively calling the function.  The part where we add 1 is the important "breaking down the work" part.  The part of the string we haven't checked yet is the part after `i`, and that part gets smaller with each call.  I don't know if you have learned about "slicing" yet, but we could use "slicing" to actually make the string get smaller and smaller with each call.  Here is a version that works that way; ignore it if you don't know slicing yet.

```
def at_check(s):
    if s == '':  # empty string
        return True
    if s[-1] == '@':  # is last character '@'?
        return False
    return at_check(s[:-1]) # recursive call with string shortened by 1
```

In this version, an empty string is the basis case.  An empty string does not contain `@`, so we return `True`.  Then if the last character is `@` we can return `False`; but otherwise we chop off the last character and recursively call the function.  Here, we break the work down by literally making the string get shorter and shorter until we are done.  But adding 1 to the index variable, and moving the index through the string, would be the same thing.

Study these examples, until you get the idea of using recursion to break down the work and make some progress on each recursive call.  Then see if you can figure out how to apply this idea to the problem of finding whether a list is sorted.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the insight. I'll hammer through the process and try to apply it to this problem.

Comment: def isSorted(checkList, i=0):
        if i >= len(checkList) - 1:
            return True
        else:
            checkList[i] >= checkList[i + 1]
            return False
        isSorted(checkList, i + 1)

Comment: that is the answer i came up with, but as it turns out, the return true will not print when its supposed to. any sugguestions why it is not printing true?

Comment: You are close!  You can't just have `checkList[i] >= checkList[i + 1]` sitting by itself; you need to actually do something with the result of that test.  I suggest you replace `else:` with `elif`, or even with just `if` (since the first `if` returns, either `elif` or `if` will work here; either way if the first `if` test is not true, the next test will happen).  Finally, you can't just recursively call the function; you need to return the result of the recursive call.  With these changes, I think you have it.

Comment: The logic you want: if the index is at or past the end of the list, return `True` (base case!); alternatively, if the current position is not in sorted order, return `False`; alternatively, return the result of a recursive call to our function that advances the index.  You can enforce the alternatives with `if` then `elif` then `else`, but in this case the `return` statements also make it possible to just use `if` then `if`.